# Factory pattern not following OPEN CLOSE Principle

Tags: java, design-patterns

When we implement factory pattern in java

Suppose the factory of products needs to be implemented, A **Product** interface is required, All the concrete classes like **AProduct**, **BProduct** and **CProduct** will implement the Product Interface.

> Public Static Product **createProduct**(String prdName);

The signature of the factory method will be as shown above.

Now if a new product say **DProduct** is introduced then we need to make changes to createProduct method, So this pattern does not follow **OPEN CLOSE Principle**.

(Open close principle is your code should be open for extension and closed for modification.)

Can I apply any other pattern over this, that will solve my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> if a new product say `DProduct` is introduced then we need to make changes to createProduct method

No, or at least not necessarily: consider [`java.sql.DriverManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DriverManager.html) class for a counterexample. Its `getConnection(String url)` is clearly a factory method, yet it handles addition of new drivers with ease, with no changes made to the method itself.

The trick is to make your factory configurable: rather than hardcoding a bunch of `if`-`then`-`else`s, you could build a "registry" of classes that maps the key passed into the factory to the name of the class, and use reflection APIs to instantiate the classes that your method needs to return.